# Intersection query on product attributes table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's a simplified version of my e-commerce schema:

```
[products]:
id
Name
Price
URL

[attributes]:
id
Description
Value

[products_attributes]:
products_id
attributes_id
```

It's the typical many-to-many relationship.

Now I need to query for all the 'Red' and 'XXL' products.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN products_attributes pa ON pa.products_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN attributes pa ON pa.attributes_id = a.id 
WHERE a.Value IN ('Red','XXL');
```

Obviously, that SQL query fetch ALL the 'Red' products, even those without the 'XXL' attribute.

How can I get just the products having both the attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to check each separately, which is one of many reasons that the EAV model is usually a bad design. You can do that by doing two subqueries for `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    P.id, P.name, P.price, P.url   -- Because we never use SELECT * except for EXISTS, COUNT(*), etc.
FROM
    Products P
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            Products_Attributes PA_RED
        INNER JOIN Attributes A_RED ON
            A_RED.attribute_id = PA_RED.attribute_id AND
            A_RED.description = 'Color' AND  -- Have you thought about the possibility that "Red" might be a value for multiple attributes?
            A_RED.value = 'Red'
        WHERE
            PA_RED.product_id = P.product_id
    ) AND
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            Products_Attributes PA_XXL
        INNER JOIN Attributes A_XXL ON
            A_XXL.attribute_id = PA_XXL.attribute_id AND
            A_XXL.description = 'Size' AND
            A_XXL.value = 'XXL'
        WHERE
            PA_XXL.product_id = P.product_id
    )
```

You could also `JOIN` to each of the tables twice:

```
SELECT
    P.id, P.name, P.price, P.url
FROM
    Products P
INNER JOIN Products_Attributes PA_RED ON PA_RED.product_id = P.product_id
INNER JOIN Attributes A_RED ON
    A_RED.attribute_id = PA_RED.attribute_id AND
    A_RED.description = 'Color' AND
    A_RED.value = 'Red'
INNER JOIN Products_Attributes PA_XXL ON PA_XXL.product_id = P.product_id
INNER JOIN Attributes A_XXL ON
    A_XXL.attribute_id = PA_XXL.attribute_id AND
    A_XXL.description = 'Size' AND
    A_XXL.value = 'XXL'
```

Of course, think about what that query looks like when you want to check 5 different attributes...

Another approach would be to check the count of matches as an aggregate. You need to be sure that the same attribute can't be matched to the same product twice though:

```
SELECT
    P.id, P.name, P.price, P.url
FROM
    Products P
INNER JOIN Products_Attributes PA ON PA.product_id = P.product_id
INNER JOIN Attributes A ON
    A.attribute_id = PA.attribute_id AND
    (A.description = 'Color' AND A.value = 'Red') OR
    (A.description = 'Size' AND A.value = 'XXL')
GROUP BY
    P.id, P.name, P.price, P.url
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: You really got the point man! Thank you!
You say EAV could be a bad design choice. Can you suggest me a better one for this purpose, maybe?

Comment: If you know your products' attributes then you put them in the table: Products would have: color, size, etc. If your products are wide-ranging (you're Amazon and you sell books, clothes, electronics, etc. all with their own attributes) then you probably don't want to use a relational database. Products like MongoDB or NoSQL might be more appropriate. It's not my area of expertise, so others might have better suggestions.

Comment: Another possibility, if you have disparate products, but a small number of categories, then you could use a model with a Products table and then 1:1 relationships to Product_Electronics, Product_Clothes, etc. as long as those subtypes each have similar attributes.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use two joins.  However, I prefer aggregation and `group by`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     products_attributes pa
     ON pa.products_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     attributes pa
     ON pa.attributes_id = a.id 
WHERE a.Value IN ('Red','XXL')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.Value) = 2;
```

Note:  this is selecting `p.*` in an aggregation query.  In general, I strongly discourage doing this.  However, in this case, the aggregation is by the primary key on the `products` table, so selecting additional columns from that table is safe.  In fact, the inclusion of additional columns is even supported by ANSI SQL for cases such as this.